# SSRS report output rendering not proper in browser for a specific report

Tags: reporting-services, output, render

I have several SSRS reports. All reports show up nice and clean. I can see the resultant output. But there is one report which is not rendering properly. I mean I know there is result set because once it finishes "Loading.." my save as option is blue and I will export it to Excel and I see the table. But on the web page itself I cannot see the table. Please see the picture attached:

[image]

So you see there is output text( "Patient mix and Patient.."). But it is squashed. I can see the complete table on "Preview" mode is Visual Studio. But on page it does not show up. Happens in IE, Firefox and Chrome. Believe me I played with format of putting the table in middle, adjusting headers and footers. No luck.

**EDIT**

I have many parameters (18 to be precise). My page for reporting services is only certain height.like may be 500px high.These parameters obscure the output. If i toggle the "show/hide parameters" button(small grayed out up arrow icon at the center of the shown image) i can see the output grid. Although the page stays still 500px. I mean the height is statically fixed to 500 px. So I hit F12 and played around with this "

ctl00_ReportOutputPlaceholder_ReportViewer_fixedTable" table values  "td" height. It was just 17 px. I made it 420 px and the page expanded and i saw the output with both the parameters and grid. I mean the page become 1000px high. Half the screen were parameters and half was the output table/grid.

So you can give me a hint in 2 ways:

1. Increase the height of the report (All of my 25 SSRS reports on server are of same 500 px height).
2. Somehow increase the height of the HTML table under"ctl00_ReportOutputPlaceholder_ReportViewer_fixedTable" value from 17 px to say 417 px.

I will keep trying but would greatly appreciate if someone can help me out.

Comment: what version of SSRS are you trying to render the report in.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Version 10.0.2531.0